# Setting up an additional domain exch 2007

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2007

I need to setup an additional domain for my company and have never done this before. From the exchange server exams I know, (create accepted domains etc) but currently the domain is with a third party, so what needs to happen with their side to point to my domain, and from the DNS perspective.

Comment: Minimally, you also need the MX record in DNS to point to your Exchange server and add it as an accepted domain so Exchange knows to handle it. There's a lot more you might have to do depending on your specific setup (recipient policy updates, spam filter configuration, domain SPF record, etc.)

Comment: So do they need to add my external IP address to their DNS, and how does their mail get forwarded to me? we are basically going to be managing a couple of new mailboxes, not all mail.

Comment: If you're not handling all the mail, that makes it completely different. Senders will look in DNS for the MX record, contact that server, and deliver mail to it. If you want to split mailbox handling over several servers, you have to do that in the mailserver, not in DNS. (Unless you mean you will have mailboxes at a subdomain...). Is your server the primary answering one, or is someone else's?

Comment: My server will be the primary answering one, there will be 10 email addresses for that domain with my server, but we may take all the emails for this domain at some stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the domain is `example.com`, then you need:

- Your server to have a public IP address on your internet connection, with port 25 forwarded in to it.
- A public hostname for your server, e.g. `mail.example.com`
- An `A` record in the DNS of `example.com` which points `mail.example.com` to your server's public IP address.
- An `MX` record in the DNS of `example.com` which names `mail.example.com` as the place to deliver mail, say MX priority 10. (Priority only really matters if you have failover servers waiting).
- A `PTR` record in the *reverse-DNS* of your Exchange Server's public IP range, mapping your Exchange server's public IP address back to `mail.example.com`. Often something you'll have to ask your ISP to do.
- A new accepted domain in Exchange for `example.com`, marked as an internal relay domain
- A new send-connector in Exchange, for `example.com`, which has a smarthost to relay unknown mailboxes to whichever server will handle the other mailboxes.

That should do it.